# Crystal Report Error "The report could not be loaded"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Currently the application is working for several users, but sometimes the system fails when they try to preview a report that they generate many times a day.

The error generated by crytal report is "The report could not be loaded", at the Visual studio level the reports have been left as an embedded resource and I have placed the tag in the app.config:

```
    <supportedRuntime version = "v4.0" sku = ".NETFramework, Version = v4.0" /> </ startup>
```

As I researched with that they should solve the majority of error with crystal report but that error keeps happening to me.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you're probably not writing VBA. Did you intend that to be [tag:VB] or [tag:VB.NET]?

Comment: Sorry is vb , thanks a lot

Comment: May you catch the exception and log the exception details? Inner exception, stack trace...